# Minimum value of $x^2+y^2$

Tags: number-theory, extremal-combinatorics

The problem is as follows:

> Find the values of $x,y$ for which $x^2+y^2$ takes the minimum value where $(x+5)^2+(y-12)^2=14$.

I was trying to solve it using the extremal principle. But, I couldn't get any far. Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Are you familiar with Lagrangian Multipliers? You are trying to minimize your function in your shifted circle, do you see it?

Comment: @GuilhermeThompson Yes. I can visualize it. And no. I do not know anything about Lagrangian multipliers.

Comment: This might help you-http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80232/need-help-finding-smallest-value-of-x2-y2

Comment: Join the origin to $(-5,12)$.

Comment: I think Lagrangian Multipliers are the way to go.

Comment: Actually, I found it in a book that archives the entrance papers of an undergrad institution that I hope to get admitted into. I believe there should be some way out. Lagrange multipliers might be a general way. But, there should be more elementary methods. If there don't seem any, can anyone please guide me to a good article where I can read about Lagrangian Multipliers?

Comment: The other two answers below have given the minimum value of $x^2+y^2$ when the question is in fact asking for $(x,y)$. I've written out the solution suggested by @AndréNicolas in his comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is asking for the point on the given circle closest to the origin. Draw a line through the origin and $(-5,12)$; it will intersect the circle at a distance of $\sqrt{(-5)^2 + 12^2} - \sqrt{14} = 13-\sqrt{14}$ from the origin.

The coördinates of the point we are looking for will therefore be:

$$(x,y) = \frac{13-\sqrt{14}}{13}(-5,12).$$

Comment: This is the best one so far.

Answer (score 1):

Solution without using Lagrangian:

Let
$$x=-5+\sqrt{14}\cos t$$
$$y=12+\sqrt{14}\sin t$$
\begin{align}
x^2+y^2&=5^2-10\sqrt{14}\cos t+14\cos^2 t+12^2+24\sqrt{14}\sin t+14\sin^2 t\\
&=5^2+12^2+14(\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t)-2\sqrt{14}(5\cos t-12\sin t)\\
&=5^2+12^2+14-2\sqrt{14}\sqrt{5^2+12^2}\cos(t+\phi)
\end{align}
As $-1\le\cos(t+\phi)\le1$,
$$183-26\sqrt{14}\le x^2+y^2\le 183+26\sqrt{14}$$

Comment: Nice. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Now, what would you do if you were to use Lagrangian multipliers?

Comment: I accepted your edit but it doesn't matter whether $\sin(t+\phi)$ or $\cos(t+\phi)$ as those will be same depending on what $\phi$ is.

Comment: Yes. Just to keep the signs correct. As it should have been $\sin(\phi-t)$ instead which did not seem quite pretty to me.

Answer (score 1):

Using Lagrange multipliers, consider $$F=x^2+y^2+\lambda\big((x+5)^2+(y-12)^2-14\big)$$ which gives $$F'_x=2 \lambda  (x+5)+2 x$$ $$F'_y=2 \lambda  (y-12)+2 y$$ $$F'_\lambda=(x+5)^2+(y-12)^2-14$$ from which $$F'_x=0\implies x=-\frac{5 \lambda }{\lambda +1}$$  $$F'_y=0\implies y=\frac{12 \lambda }{\lambda +1}$$ Plugging in the last partial derivative $$F'_\lambda=0 \implies \frac{169}{(\lambda +1)^2}-14=0$$ from which two solutions $$\lambda_1=-1-\frac{13}{\sqrt{14}}$$  $$\lambda_2=-1+\frac{13}{\sqrt{14}}$$ Computing the values of $x$ and $y$ for $\lambda_1$ yields to $x^2+y^2=183+26 \sqrt{14}$; doing the same for $\lambda_2$ yields to $x^2+y^2=183-26 \sqrt{14}$.

This is the same as what Kay K. elegantly answered.

Comment: Nice. This is way more general. It'd help me in future problems. @Kay K. 's answer is more specific and elegant. So I accept his one. Thanks anyway. +1

Comment: You are welcome ! Lagrange multipliers are just great for so many problems.